# FileSystemWatcher unreliable for changes in subdirectory

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I am currently implementing file content watchers for OpenFOAM output files. These files get written by OpenFOAM in an Unix environment and consumed by my applications in a Windows environment.

Please consider my first, *working* watcher for convergence files (these files get updated after each iteration of the solution):

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher;
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(WatchPath, "convergenceUp*.out");
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Files = Directory.GetFiles(WatchPath, "convergenceUp*.out").OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); // Update List of all files in the directory
    ReadFiles(); // Do fancy stuff with the files
}
```

This works as expected. Everytime a file matching the pattern is changed in the watched directory (Notepad++ does notify me that the file has changed aswell) the files are processed.

Moving on from this simple "all files are in one directory" scenario I started to build a watcher for a different type of file (Force function objects for those familiar with OpenFOAM). These files are saved in a hierarchical folder structure like thus:

```
NameOfFunctionObject
|_StartTimeOfSolutionSetup#1
| |_forces.dat
|_StartTimeOfSolutionSetup#2
  |_forces.dat
```

My goal is to read all forces.dat from "NameOfFunctionObject" and do some trickery with all the contained data. Additionally I also like to have the chance of reading and watching just one file. So my implementation (which borrows heavily from the above) currently looks like this:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher;
if (isSingleFile)
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Directory.GetParent(WatchPath).ToString(), Path.GetFileName(WatchPath));
else
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(WatchPath, "forces.dat");
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = !isSingleFile;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.Security;
watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
watcher.Deleted += Watcher_Deleted;
watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
watcher.Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = isWatchEnabled;
```

So depending on wether I want to watch just one file or multiple files I set up the directory to watch and the file filter. If I watch multiple files I set the watcher to watch subdirectories aswell. Because of vigorous testing I filter for all notifications and catch all watcher events.

If I test the single file option, everything works as expected, changes to the file are reported and processed correctly (again, the check with trusty old Notepad++ works)
On testing the multi-file option though, things get pear shaped.
The file paths are correct, the initial read works as expected. But neither watcher event fires. Here comes the curious bit: Notepad++ beeps still away, saying the file has changed, Windows explorer shows a new file date and a new file size. If I save the file within Notepad++, the watcher gets triggered. If I create a new file matching the pattern insinde the watched directory (top level or below does not matter!) the watcher gets triggered. Even watching for a filter of *.* to catch creation of temporary files does not trigger, so it is safe to assume that no temporary files are created.

In general, the watcher behaves as expected, it can detect changes to a single file, it can detect creations of files in the root watched folder and its subfolders. It just fails to recognise non-windows-changes to a file once it is located in a subfolder. Is this behaviour by design? And more importantly: how can I work elegantly around it without resorting to using a timer and polling by hand?

Comment: Is there a lot of changes? or are we only talking a few files (when its not working)

Comment: There are currently 6 files being watched, with a change occuring in one of them around every minute, so it is not a high frequency issue

Comment: I feel your pain, try increasing the buffer, but filesystemwatcher can be natoriously unreliable in my experience, you might want to poll as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be relevant to you

`FileSystemWatcher` uses [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *Winapi* call with a few relevant flags

> When you first call `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, the system allocates a
>   buffer to store change information. This buffer is associated with the
>   directory handle until it is closed and its size does not change
>   during its lifetime. Directory changes that occur between calls to
>   this function are added to the buffer and then returned with the next
>   call. **If the buffer overflows, the entire contents of the buffer are
>   discarded**

The analogue in `FileSystemWatcher` is the [`FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx) property

> **Remarks** You can set the buffer to 4 KB or larger, but it must not
>   exceed 64 KB. If you try to set the InternalBufferSize property to
>   less than 4096 bytes, your value is discarded and the
>   InternalBufferSize property is set to 4096 bytes. For best
>   performance, use a multiple of 4 KB on Intel-based computers.
>
> The system notifies the component of file changes, and it stores those
>   changes in a buffer the component creates and passes to the APIs. **Each
>   event can use up to 16 bytes of memory**, not including the file name.
>   **If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow.
>   This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory**,
>   and it will only provide blanket notification. Increasing the size of
>   the buffer can prevent missing file system change events. However,
>   increasing buffer size is expensive, because it comes from non-paged
>   memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so keep the buffer as small
>   as possible. **To avoid a buffer overflow, use the NotifyFilter and
>   IncludeSubdirectories properties to filter out unwanted change
>   notifications**.

If worse comes to worse, you can use a mix of polling and tracking, it has helped me out of trouble a few times

Comment: I now increased the buffer (to no avail) but start a timer with interval 5 minutes to trigger polling as a backup. If the watcher would detect a change it would reset the timer. So it is less than polling and more like forcing to reload. Since it wont be files of outstanding size I should be fine. Thank you!